# Impossible to extract data from this url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first post here. It has been 5 months since I have been learning python from scratch, on my own, and I did acquire most of my knowledge thanks to this forum, and I am now able to create webbots which can easily scrape all types of data, especially in sport betting sites.

Though for this particular need, there is one site from which I cannot extract what I am looking for:

[winamax](https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs#!/sports)

I would like to get all links from all football events (on the left side, for example:

```
"https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs#!/match/prelive/7894014"
```

but when I look at the source code, or when I print my soup, I just get nothing.

```
url = "https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs#!/sports"
urlRequest = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
#of course, proxies and headers are defined beforehand
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlRequest.content)
print(soup)
```

For all bookmakers I have already come up with, there was always either a simple html tree structure in which all items were easy to find, or a hidden javascript file, or a json link.
But for this one, even when trying to catch the flow with Firebug, I cannot find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance if someone has an idea on how to get that (I considered using PhantomJS but not tried yet).

EDIT:

@ssundarraj:
Hereunder the header, the same I have been using in all my projects, so not relevant in my opinion, but anyway, here it is:

```
AgentsFile='UserAgents.txt'
lines = open(AgentsFile).read().splitlines()
myline =random.choice(lines)
headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language':'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer' : 'https://www.winamax.fr',
    'User-Agent': myline}
```

EDIT2:

@Chris Lear

> using firebug, in the net panel, you can search through all the
>   response bodies (there's a checkbox called "Response Bodies" that
>   appears when you click the search box). That will show you that the
>   data is being fetched by json. I'll leave you to try to make sense of
>   it, but that might give you a start (searching for ids is probably
>   best)

I checked the box you mentioned hereabove, but with no effect :(
With or without filter, nothing is displayed in my network panel, as you can see on the picture:

[nothing caught](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjoC6.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the headers?

Comment: using firebug, in the net panel, you can search through all the response bodies (there's a checkbox called "Response Bodies" that appears when you click the search box). That will show you that the data is being fetched by json. I'll leave you to try to make sense of it, but that might give you a start (searching for ids is probably best)

Answer (score 0):

Used firebug and find out this.
Make POST request to https://www.winamax.fr/betting/slider/slider.php with parameters:

- key=050e42fb0761c96526e8510eda89248f
- lang=FR

Don't know if key is changing but now it works.

Comment: Thank you Radek, but undortunately, the slider url only concerns the carousel with 3 or 4 cycling images, corresponding to a few sport events... still not what I am looking for (the whole list of events)